# Jquery change text on click to "show" or "hide"

Tags: jquery

In this script, when the "Show" link is clicked, and the preview image is shown, the link text should change to "Hide". It only works after the 3rd click.

```
<span id='previewLinks'><br/><a id='showPreview' title='".get_option('my_theme')."'>Show</a>

$('#showPreview').click
(
    function(e) 
    {
    var myImage = $('#my_theme :selected').val();
    $('#largePreview').slideToggle(0, function() {
        $('#showPreview').text($(this).is(':visible') ? 'Hide' : 'Show');
    });
    $('#largePreview').attr('src', '<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_directory') ?>/styles/'+myImage+'/screenshot-help.jpg');
    }
);
```

Comment: Is `#largePreview` initially shown or hidden?

Comment: Any reason you are using `slideToggle` with a duration of zero instead of `hide()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try this:

```
$('#showPreview').click(
    function(e) {
    var myImage = $('#my_theme :selected').val();
    $('#largePreview').slideToggle(0, function() {
        $('#showPreview').text($(this).is(':visible') ? 'Hide' : 'Show');
    });
    $('#largePreview').attr('src', '<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_directory') ?>/styles/'+myImage+'/screenshot-help.jpg');
    }).click();
```

Comment: @Scott B here i add an initial `click()`

Answer (score 1):

The reason it doesn't work initially is because `#largePreview` must have a display state opposite from what you are assuming. This change may fix it. Note the `!`

```
$('#showPreview').text(!$(this).is(':visible') ? 'Hide' : 'Show');
```

Or you may need to change the css for `#largePreview`.

Comment: That's kind of anti-intuitive isn't it? `IF hidden THEN output "hide"`, `IF visible Then output "show"`.

Comment: @Jasper - yeah, I answered a question like this a few days ago and the user actually wanted it that way. Confused me, but I guess some people view it that way.

Answer (score 0):

just figure out what you did wrong:

[See example here.](http://jsfiddle.net/Dgc3t/5/)

1. Use

```
$(document).ready(function(){
});
```

2. `<a href="javascript:;"> TEXT </a> will give you a right anchor`

Hope it helps!
Thanks to Jasper Too.

Comment: `$(this).filter(":visible")` always returns true so the text is always set to "Hide". Using `.is()` instead of `.filter()` will return `true`/`false`: `$(this).is(":visible")`. You can also check the `length` property of the jQuery object after filtering down to only visible elements: `$(this).filter(":visible").length > 0`. Here is an updated version of your jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Dgc3t/5/